# Function parameter in variadic template

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to write a variadic template class with functions as template parameter ?

Theses are valid c++ declarations

```
template <typename ...Types> class foo;

template <int func(int)>  class bar;
```

Would it be possible to do something like

```
template <int func(int)...> class foobar;
```

I tried a lot of different syntax like

```
template <int ...func(int)> class foobar;
```

and nothing is compiling (I am using gcc 8.1.0 with -std=c++17)

Comment: please include one of your attempts together with the error message you get, this will help to answer your question and make the question more accesible for future readers

Comment: `template <auto...funcs> class foobar{};` (C++17) if your are very lazy and don't check types ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Syntax is:

```
template <int (*...Fs)(int)> class foobar {};
```

which allows

```
int f1(int);
int f2(int);

foobar<&f1, &f2, &f1> obj;
```

Using alias might help you to have more natural syntax:

```
using f_int_int = int (*)(int);
template <f_int_int...Fs> class foobar {};
```

or even (thanks to Yakk's comment):

```
template <typename T> using id_t = T;
template <id_t<int(*)(int)>...Fs> class foobar {};
```

Comment: Or - more resembling the original template (`template <int func(int)>`) - `template <int (...func)(int)>`

Comment: @GontranZipper If you accept this answer it'll be removed from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: I find `template<class T>using id_t=T;` then `template<id_t<int(*)(int)> ...Fs>` to less confusing than having to work out where `...` goes in `int(*)(int)`.  But that is just me.